# Loading image on React creates a blank screen

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm learning react right now and I'm trying to build a simple page as practice. However, I am trying to put an image in the navbar of the page but with the image loaded, all my page displays is the background color. I can't see the image itself or any of the text. When I comment out the image tag, my page looks normal and everything is displayed correctly. What's causing this?

Here's my code.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'


export default function Navbar() {
    return (
        <div id="navbar">
            <img src={require('/images/logo.png')} id="logo" width="20" height="20"/>
            <h3 id="nav1">Navbar goes here</h3>
            <h4 id="nav2">React Course - Project 1</h4>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I've tried messing with the width and height, thinking maybe the image was too big. I put both to 20 pixels and the problem remains. With the image "loaded", I tried to see if I could scroll but I couldn't. It seems like everything else just gets deleted when the image is loaded.

Comment: Firstly, the error will be in the terminal. However, it's most likely caused by `require('/images/logo.png')`. The path passed to `require` is a local filesystem path *not* a URL. You are telling the code there is an `images` folder on the root of your filesystem (unlikely). Where is the image in your directory structure relative to the file you shared the code of? Lets say the `images` folder was next to the file above. In this case it would be `require('./images/logo.png')`. If the `images` folder is one directory up from this file, it would be `require('../images/logo.png')`, for example.

Answer (score -1):

To display an image in React, you should import the image directly using ES6 module syntax. Here's an updated version of your code that should resolve the issue:

```js
import React from 'react';
import logo from '/images/logo.png';

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <div id="navbar">
      <img src={logo} id="logo" width="20" height="20" alt="Logo" />
      <h3 id="nav1">Navbar goes here</h3>
      <h4 id="nav2">React Course - Project 1</h4>
    </div>
  );
}
```

By using the correct import syntax, the image should be displayed in the navbar without interfering with the other content on the page.